# Spotify Web Playback SDK

Tags: reactjs, api, tokens

estoy haciendo una aplicación con react y me gastaría implementar la API de Spotify, la duda que tengo es si para conectarme al reproductor necesito iniciar sesión en la aplicación o si puedo usar la función "cast"/"dispositivos" de Spotify Android, esto debido a que en la pc que va a estar alojada la web no va a tener teclado/mouse u otra entrada. Gracias de antemano